# Flutter - Firebase RTDB, The method forEach was called on null

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

The only this I changed in my code and Firebase rtdb is where the data is being fetched from.

Before data was in: "users" - "parents" (Code worked perfectly here)

Now data is in: "users" - schoolName.toString() - "parents" (Code causes an error)

How can I approach/solve this issue?

Thanks.

Error:

```
E/flutter ( 8683): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'forEach' was called on null.

E/flutter ( 8683): Tried calling: forEach(Closure: (dynamic, dynamic) => void)
```

Code:

```
Future<List> getParentDetails() async {
    schoolName = await getSchoolName();
    databaseReference
        .child("users")
        .child(schoolName.toString())
        .child("parents")
        .onValue
        .listen(
      (event) {
        if (event.snapshot.exists) {
          setState(
            () {
              var value = event.snapshot.value;
              parentList = Map.from(value)
                  .values
                  .map((e) => Parents.fromJson(Map.from(e)))
                  .toList();
            },
          );
        } else {
          print("No Data Exists");
        }
      },
    );
    return parentList;
  }
```

UI Code:

```
ListView.builder(
              itemCount: parentList.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, int index) {
                final Parents parents = parentList[index];
                final String driverEmail = parents.email;
                final String driverName = parents.name;
                final String driverPhone = parents.phone;
                // final driverRandomId = parents.randomId;
                // final String driverUID = driver.uid;
                return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Card(
                    elevation: 0.2,
                    child: ExpansionTile(
                      // collapsedBackgroundColor: Colors.grey,
                      title: Text(
                        driverName.toUpperCase(),
                        style: GoogleFonts.lexendMega(
                          fontSize: 12,
                        ),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      ),
                      children: [
                        Column(
                          children: [
                            Text(
                              driverEmail,
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              style: GoogleFonts.lexendMega(fontSize: 12),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 5,
                            ),
                            Text(
                              driverPhone,
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              style: GoogleFonts.lexendMega(fontSize: 12),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 5,
                            ),
                          ],
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
```

Class Code:

```
class Parents {
  final String email;
  final String name;
  final String phone;

  Parents({
    this.email,
    this.name,
    this.phone,
  });

  static Parents fromJson(Map<String, String> json) {
    return Parents(
      email: json['email'],
      name: json['name'],
      phone: json['phone'],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to check whether your snapshot has some data (I'm assuming it returns an `AsyncSnapshot`, which is also used by widgets like `StreamBuilder` and `FutureBuilder`.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AsyncSnapshot-class.html

In that case, you can call `event.snapshot.hasData` to determine whether data is null. If it is, you can instead return an empty list.

I assume you're using this approach as opposed to a `FutureBuilder` to keep your business logic and UI separate? If there's no specific reasoning, you might want to consider to instead use a `FutureBuilder` or `StreamBuilder` instead.

Comment: I have updated my code above. 

Event.snapshot.exists has NO data. However the node from which I'm trying to get data from, does have data. 

In my UI, I'm using Listview.builder to display the list of parents. (I've added the code above)